# protoc.exe causes recompilation of the entire solution when used a prebuild step

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, protocol-buffers

I have a very large solution, with several projects and many source files and schemas.

One of the projects has a prebuild step to execute protoc.exe on a schemas directory, which creates many source files that are compiled as part of the project.

The problem is that protoc.exe overwrites even files that were not changed, which causes many files, and files depending on them to be recompiled and eventually almost the entire solution gets recompiled every time I compile the anything.

Is there a better way to use protoc.exe to prevent this problem?

I think the source the problem is the fact that protoc.exe overwrites files that are exactly the same.

I use C++ on Visual Studio 2015

Comment: You could use GNU make with an appropriate rule in the prebuild step (I suspect you have a simple script there, that applies to all `.proto` files).

Comment: actually protoc.exe support receiving an input and output directories and compiling all the schemas.

Comment: But it doesn't work like make does, but obviously compiles all `.proto` files independently if these were changed or not. AFAIK there's no option, you can tell `protoc.exe` to do so.

Answer (score 0):

make a wrapper around your proc.exe which, after running it, resets modification time for files which did not change.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are calling `protoc` in such a way that you are telling it to regenerate code for every `.proto` file, when you can actually tell it to just generate code for a particular file.

For example let's say we have two files `test1.proto` and `test2.proto`, with a dependency between them:

```
// test1.proto
syntax = "proto2";
import "test2.proto";
message Foo {
  optional Bar bar = 1;
}

// test2.proto
syntax = "proto2";
message Bar {
  optional int32 count = 1;
}
```

If `test1.proto` changes then we can tell `protoc` to rebuild the code for just that file and not for `test2.proto`:

```
protoc --cpp_out=. test1.proto
```

This generates `test1.pb.h` and `test1.pb.cc`, but it does not generate `test2.pb.h` or `test2.pb.cc`. Just make sure `protoc` can find any imports it needs--for this you may need to pass `-Ipath/to/other/protos`.